# Using grep to find and estimate the total # of shell scripts in the current dir

Tags: shell, unix, grep

New to UNIX, currently learning UNIX via secureshell in a class. We've been given a few basic assignments such as creating loops and finding files. Our last assignment asked us to

> write code that will estimate the number of shell scripts in the current directory and then print out that total number as "Estimated number of shell script files in this directory:"

Unlike in our previous assignments we are now allowed to use conditional loops, we are encouraged to use grep and wc statements.

On a basic level I know I can enter

> ls * .sh

to find all shell scripts in the current directory. Unfortunately, this doesn't estimate the total number or use grep. Hence my question, I imagine he wants us to go

> grep -f .sh (or something)

but I'm not exactly sure if I am on the right path and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank You

Comment: He may be assuming that files have a certain naming convention, so you would start by finding all the files that have that convention, then using grep to search for a string that's common to all shell scripts (maybe #!/bin/sh, for example).

Comment: Yes, I didn't add the entire text, but at the end it had "A shell
script will be defined as a text file that begins with #!/bin/sh."

Comment: You should add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
echo "Estimated number of shell script files in this directory:" `ls *.sh | wc -l`
```

Comment: Initially that's what I did, but like I previous stated our assignment had a "hint" embedded in the bottom which said we SHOULD (In bold) look up grep and wc commands. Granted this doesn't mean we need to use them, but given past behavior this is usually means use them in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
find . -executable -execdir file {} + | egrep '\.sh: | Bourne| bash' | wc -l
```

1. Find all files in the current directory (`.`) which are executable.
2. For each file, run the `file(1)` command, which tries to guess what type of file it is (not perfect).
3. Grep for known patterns: filenames ending with `.sh`, or file types containing "Bourne" or "bash".
4. Count lines.

Comment: Indeed it does, but as a new programmer in UNIX I feel it may be a bit complicated, or perhaps not the route I am supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

Huhu, there's a trap, .sh file are not always shell script as the extension is not mandatory.

What tells you this is a shell script will be the Shebang `#!/bin/*sh` ( I put a * as it could be bash, csh, tcsh, zsh, which are shells) at top of line, hence the hint to use grep, so the best answer would be:

`grep '^#!/bin/.*sh' * | wc -l`

This give output:

```
sensible-pager:#!/bin/sh
service:#!/bin/sh
shelltest:#!/bin/bash
smbtar:#!/bin/sh
```

grep works with regular expression by default, so the match `#!/bin/.*sh` will match files with a line starting (the `^`) by `#!/bin/` followed by 0 or unlimited characters `.*` followed by `sh`

You may test regex and get explanation of them on http://regex101.com

Piping the result to wc -l to get the number of files containing this.

To display the result, backticks or `$()` in an echo line is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l <string> *
```

will return a list of all files that contain  in the current directory.  Pipe that output into `wc -l` and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
ls | grep .sh > tmp
wc tmp
```

That will print the number of lines, bytes and charcters of 'tmp' file. But in 'tmp' there's a line for each *.sh file in your working directory. So the number of lines will give an estimated number of shell scripts you have.

```
wc tmp | awk '{print $1}' # Using awk to filter that output like...
wc -l tmp # Which it returns the number of lines follow by the name of file
```

But as many people say, the only certain way to know a file is a shell script is by taking a look at the first line an see if there is #!/bin/bash. If you wanna develop it that way, keep in mind:

```
cat possible_script.x | head -n1 # That will give you the first line.
```